# i want to use only 6 months of every year to work with in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, extract

i have dates in dataframe from **2015-01-01 00:00:00** to **2022-09-05 23:59:00**

I want to extract   all the data inbetween **04-01 00:00:00** and ****10-31** 23:59:59**
i tried
`

```
filtered_df = df.loc[(df['date'] >= '04-01 00:00:00')
                     & (df['date'] < '10-31 23:59:59')]
filtered_df.head()
```

`it says

```
TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and str
```

althrough when i type df.dtypes date is
datetime64[ns]

it should show dates like **after** 2015-10-31 23:59:59 there **is**  2016-04-01 00:00:00
not any other date until it is within these 6 months

Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 1):

```py
df[(df.date.dt.month>=4) & (df.date.dt.month<=10)]
```

Key point is `.dt` that allows datetime specific accessor (a little bit like `.str` allows string specific methods.